# dialogflow custom payload json

Tags: node.js, json, dialogflow-es

I am sending a custom payload it is generating carousel of 3 card at output. All the card have book now button and when book now is pressed my book now intent is triggered. The question is how to detect which button is pressed by the user since all the buttons have similar name?

```
    {

        "fulfillmentMessages": [
            {
                "payload": {
                    "facebook": {
                        "attachment": {
                            "payload": {
                                "template_type": "generic",
                                "elements": [
                                    {
                                        "image_url": "https://texasstation.sclv.com/~/media/Images/Page-Background-Images/Texas/TS_Hotel_King_lowrez.jpg?h=630&la=en&w=1080",
                                        "title": "Hotel California",
                                        "buttons": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "postback",
                                                "title": "Book Now",
                                                "payload": "Book Now"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "subtitle": "5 Star \nPrice: $100 Per Day"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMxWAipET12AtXfzCH4tkpiawneQ201ySPYkEPQZkMxpt6ebp5_Q",
                                        "title": "Hotel Castleway",
                                        "buttons": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "postback",
                                                "title": "Book Now",
                                                "payload": "Book Now"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "subtitle": "4 Star \nPrice: $60 Per Day"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSk2p33NIGvulmlbJu9mEGU_PUoOJqqs_MYcQ1YhkIZqcDaBl2Z",
                                        "title": "Pearl Continental",
                                        "buttons": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "postback",
                                                "title": "Book Now",
                                                "payload": "Book Now"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "subtitle": "7 Star \nPrice: 250$ Per Day"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image_aspect_ratio": "horizontal"
                            },
                            "type": "template"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "platform": "FACEBOOK"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Name can be same but you can differ the payload

Comment: can you please explain how? If the name is same it will still invoke the same intent

Comment: intents are getting triggred on payload, title is just wrapper of your payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the payload as Nikhil said. The title will show the same in all buttons, but on click they will have different values:

```
{
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "payload": {
                "facebook": {
                    "attachment": {
                        "payload": {
                            "template_type": "generic",
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://texasstation.sclv.com/~/media/Images/Page-Background-Images/Texas/TS_Hotel_King_lowrez.jpg?h=630&la=en&w=1080",
                                    "title": "Hotel California",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "postback",
                                            "title": "Book Now",
                                            "payload": "Book california"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "subtitle": "5 Star \nPrice: $100 Per Day"
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMxWAipET12AtXfzCH4tkpiawneQ201ySPYkEPQZkMxpt6ebp5_Q",
                                    "title": "Hotel Castleway",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "postback",
                                            "title": "Book Now",
                                            "payload": "Book Castleway"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "subtitle": "4 Star \nPrice: $60 Per Day"enter code here
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSk2p33NIGvulmlbJu9mEGU_PUoOJqqs_MYcQ1YhkIZqcDaBl2Z",
                                    "title": "Pearl Continental",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "postback",
                                            "title": "Book Now",
                                            "payload": "Book Pearl"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "subtitle": "7 Star \nPrice: 250$ Per Day"
                                }
                            ],
                            "image_aspect_ratio": "horizontal"
                        },
                        "type": "template"
                    }
                }
            },
            "platform": "FACEBOOK"
        },
    ]
}
```